# Reading text/number mixed CSV files as tables in Octave

Tags: octave

is there an easy way in octave to load data from a csv in a data structure similar to dataframes in R? I tries csvread dlmread but octave keeps reading test a imaginary numbers, plus I'd like to have column's headers as references. I saw that there are some examples online which see way too twisted, how is it possible that there is not a function or something similar to dataframe of R? I say a package called dataframe but I can't seem to figure out how it works. Any tip or suggestion?

```
csvread('x') %returns 1 column imaginary numbers
dlmread('x') %returns N columns imaginary numbers
```

Any working alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you unable to make the dataframe package work? You need to be more specific. Here's a simple example:

```
$ cat cars.csv 
Year,Make,Model
1997,Ford,E350
2000,Mercury,Cougar

$ octave
octave-cli-3.8.2:1> pkg load dataframe
octave-cli-3.8.2:2> cars = dataframe ("cars.csv")
cars = dataframe with 2 rows and 3 columns
Src: cars.csv                             
_1   Year    Make  Model                  
Nr double    char   char                  
 1   1997    Ford   E350                  
 2   2000 Mercury Cougar
```

Comment: When I try to open my CSV file as a dataframe I get this message "Error was: cell2mat: wrong type elements or mixed cells, structs, and matrices"

Comment: @NetWanderer that is a problem reading your file. That can either be a problem on the dataframe package, or a problem on your file.

Comment: I can open this file with anything else I try. I guess there might be some minor bug in the dataframe package.

Comment: @NetWanderer just show your file. The top 5-10 lines should be enough for people to be able to help you. There is also a csvread function in octave but if that is also failing, and if you want help, you need to give more information