# Read file having mixed data type in the same column

Tags: octave, file-handling

I have to read a file using octave which has the following format

```
0 0.232 0.565
2 0.232 name1
1 0.2314 0.2546
3 0.2455
4 0.2544 name2
```

Essentially the third column can be an string or a float while the first column is an integer and the second column is a float.

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407344/reading-text-number-mixed-csv-files-as-tables-in-octave) which requires me to install a package. I want to avoid installing new packages. Is there any solution using built-in functions ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can read it as string, and then convert it using the `str2double` function. If it is not a number, it will return NaN. However, you could not store numbers and strings in the same vector as they are not the same type.

A possible solution is to split the last vector in two new vectors, one containing strings, in which you set empty string where there was a number; the other vector containing the numbers, and zero or NaN where there was a string.

Reference : [str2double](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/String-Conversions.html#XREFstr2double)

Comment: How to read the whole file as a string in one go. I want to read each line as a string without using any loops. I have tried textscan but it reads each element in a separate string

Comment: You can use the [dlmread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html#inputarg_delimiter) function to read the whole file and store it in a string matrix.

Comment: It is not working as expected, can you post the exact syntax for the text file mentioned in the question.